# What is the best bike for me?

Tags: road-bike, bike-fit, beginner

I'm a man 5'8" planning to get a new bike as a beginner. looking for going around the city + fitness. My budget under $800. The bike that I need it should make me fall in love with Road bikes.

Comment: The best bike for you is a used one.  (See if a friend or relative doesn't have a suitable one gathering dust in their garage.)  After you've owned it for a year or so you will be able to better choose a new bike.

Comment: Hi, welcome to bicycles!  I'm afraid that we can't do recommendation questions because they don't have any longevity - the likelihood that someone even a year from now will be considering exactly the same options is very low, so any answers will not have much value.  You might want to take the [tour] to learn more.

Comment: @DavidW I don’t think recommending specific bike models is necessary to answer this question. Guiding OP along the right category of bike is all that’s needed.

Comment: @MaplePanda Fair comment, though in that case I might have flagged to close as "needs more details." ;)  I think I read "should make me fall in love with road bikes" as indicating OP wanted a _specific_ road bike recommendation.

Comment: Spend under $600 on the bike, spend $100 on cloths/shoes/helmet that make you comfortable and safe riding in your climate, have $100 for maintenance and repairs (e.g. puncture repairs) and incidentals.

Answer (score 4):

The best bike for you is one that you want to ride.

Your bike needs to be comfortable **TO YOU** which means the correct size.

It needs to suit your needs, whether that be commuting, training, shopping, adventure, offroad.

It needs to be affordable without breaking your budget, and leave enough spare cash for those extras like helmet, a bag, tools, spares, gloves, or whatever else you need.

---

The reason that a used bike is often suggested is because they are generally a lot cheaper than a new bike, plus in these C19 days the supply chain can be lumpy.

A used bike can let you ride the bike you think you want, and then you can buy another used bike of a style that grows on you later.  It is not uncommon for riders to want a squishy MTB to ride to work/school, and then realise how slow they are compared to something more road-oriented   (for example)

On the other hand, a new bike comes with some sort of warranty depending on your location.   Some people cannot stand the idea of riding a bike that someone else has ridden, so new is their only option.   That's okay too, but it costs more.

A bike that is bought with the best intentions but only gets a few rides before being stored, that's a ROPA (*ridden once, put away*) or a "Garage Princess"   If you have one of those in your extended family, then see if you can borrow it for a try.